# How to limit control flow during unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, bestpractice, httpcalloutmock

I want to limit the control flow during a unit test so that it does not leave the method being tested. The unit test is for a controller method, and in that method the controller creates an object and calls a method on that object.

```
public class MyController {
    void myMethod() {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        Integer x = obj.someMethod(); 
    }
}
```

How do I stop someMethod() from actually being called and instead provide a test value for x?

In my research I found documentation on mocking HttpRequest objects (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm), but no options for mocking other objects.

I also found the Test.isRunningTest() boolean that indicates whether a test is running, meaning that I could change my production code to:

```
public class MyController {
    void myMethod() {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();

        Integer x;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            x = obj.someMethod(); // Call method if not in test    
        } else {
            x = 1; // Test Value
        }
    }
}
```

But this limits the test to just one test value, and I'd like to avoid modifying production code for the sake of a test if I can help it.

So I guess the question in full is: how to provide a test value for 'x' and not call someMethod() during a test without modifying production code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "intercept" a call to create a new object and/or interrupt a function/constructor. Instead, try to break your code up into segments that you can adjust independently, or, if you *really* need to, simply make the variable have a bigger scope and make it @TestVisible:

```
public class MyController {
    @TestVisible transient Integer x;
    void myMethod() {
        if(x == null) {
            x = obj.someMethod();
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

This way, you can then do:

```
MyController mc = new MyController();
mc.x = 5;
mc.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make x a member variable.

Then you could do something like:

```
MyController mc = new MyController();
mc.x = 10;
```